# Populating a dropdown box with already-existing options in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making an add records form for a spreadsheet of mine, and let's say that I want one of the controls to be a dropdown that is populated by unique entries under a certain column "type". However, I want to also make it such that the dropbox always has a initial option to "add new type" and upon such selection, it becomes a regular text box. How would I do this in VBA?

Comment: You can use the Visibility property and OnChange events for the dropdown box to show/hide a textbox.  However, to do this properly and give an example, I don't think I would be able to explain it on SO.  If you have a workbook already started, then modifying it would be a lot easier.

Comment: I think I understand.  ComboBox can accept text.   I think what you'd want to do is have an event handle the case where you input text into it instead of a dropdown, then add the Text to the RowSource for that dropdown so that future uses it's listed??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a control type at run time. The easiest thing to do is create a combo box and a text box. Set the text box visibility to false. Then in the onchange event of the combo box your code will unhide the text box and hide the combo box. You will also need a save button so that when it is clicked it will add the option to the drop down, clear the text box, hide the text box, hide the button and unhide the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's my idea of how to tackle this.

1. Create 2 hidden elements (Visibility = False), one a TextBox and one a CommandButton.
2. Populate your ComboBox with the values from the sheet under column "type"
3. Add one more entry AddItem with wording such as "Add new item..."
4. When the user selects "Add new item...", change the Visibility of the TextBox & CommandButtons to True
5. When the user clicks the CommandButton, add the phrase to the column and add a new element to the ComboBox

I have created a mockup UserForm and code that does a little more than just this; it also styles the user entry to sentence case (consistency purposes) and checks to make sure the value isn't already in the column.

**Excel Sheet with "type" column**

[image: Excel layout with values for type]

**UserForm with name labels**

[image: combobox,textbox,commandbutton userform]

**UserForm Code**

```
Private Sub bAdd_Click()
Dim str As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim ro As Integer
    'Makes sure there is an entry, adds it to the Sheet and then updates the dropdown
    If Len(Me.tbNew) > 0 Then
        'Converts user entry to "Sentance Case" for better readability
        str = StrConv(Me.tbNew, vbProperCase)

        'Finds out if the entry already exists
        Set rng = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Number = 0
        'Searches for duplicate; if found, then ListIndex of cbColor is modified without inserting new value (prevents duplicates)
        ro = rng.Find(str, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        Debug.Print Err.Number
        'Ensures a user doesn't add the same value twice
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1) = str
            Me.cbColor.AddItem StrConv(Me.tbNew, vbProperCase), Me.cbColor.ListCount - 1
            Me.cbColor.ListIndex = Me.cbColor.ListCount - 2
        Else
            Me.cbColor.ListIndex = ro - 2
        End If
        'Resets and hides user form entries
        Me.tbNew = vbNullString
        Me.tbNew.Visible = False
        Me.bAdd.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub bClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cbColor_Change()
    'Visibility is toggled based on if the user selected the last element in the dropdown
    Me.bAdd.Visible = Me.cbColor.ListIndex = Me.cbColor.ListCount - 1
    Me.tbNew.Visible = Me.cbColor.ListIndex = Me.cbColor.ListCount - 1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Populate from the sheet
    For a = 2 To Sheets(1).Cells(Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Row
        Me.cbColor.AddItem Sheets(1).Cells(a, 1)
    Next
    'Add option for new type
    Me.cbColor.AddItem "Add new type..."
End Sub
```